# Find the D,E and F values with R

Tags: r, statistics

My task sounds like:

> Here is some generic output from a multiple regression analysis of a
>   model predicting Y from three numeric variables X1, X2, and X3  on n =
>   25 observations. I have replaced some of the values in the output by
>   letters. You are to use the remaining values to compute the values for
>   A, B, C,  … , K. Please make it crystal clear how you obtained your
>   answers.

Coefficients:

```
        Estimate    Std. Error    t value   Pr(>|t|)   

(Intercept)  3.49526    2.63720   1.325   0.19929   

X1          -1.17573    0.31557   -3.725734   D

X2           0.03876    0.03193   1.213905     E   

X3          -0.15228    0.05011  -3.038914     F
```

---

```
Residual standard error: 0.754 on 21 degrees of freedom

Multiple R-squared:  0.625634,  Adjusted R-squared:  0.7150102

F-statistic:  11.7 on 3 and 21 DF,  p-value: 0.0001016
```

anova(model)

Analysis of Variance Table

```
Response: Y

      Df  Sum Sq Mean Sq F value    Pr(>F)    

X1         1  8.6400  8.6400 15.2122 0.0008244 ***

X2         1  6.0468  6.0468 10.6465 0.0037181 ** 

X3         1  5.2459  5.2459  9.2362 0.0062376 ** 

Residuals  21 11.9273  0.5680
```

How may i find D,E and F values with R studio comands?

Comment: This is about R, not RStudio.

Comment: If your question is the math behind it, this belongs on [CrossValidated](http://stats.stackexchange.com/). If your question is how to access the numbers programmatically from a model, then `summary(lm(mpg~cyl, data=mtcars))$coef` is a `matrix`, so you can use the columns and rows to calculate whatever you need.

Comment: this looks like a homework question without any evidence of research effort ...

Comment: @BenBolker probably it's my fault that it's looks like you say for you, but task is the task and i don't know what i should  to do to make this task looking more realistic for you

Comment: In all of my years as a student, grad student, and in various areas of industry, I have seen this problem come up several times. And it was *always* in homework. I don't think BenBolker was talking about realism, he was talking about you asking somebody to do your homework for you with no indication that you did anything other than scratch your head. While I was teaching, when a student walked in with questions, my first question to them was always "what did you try?", and if they had nothing then their path was fairly evident. We can help, but meet us half-way.

Comment: yes.  Homework is perfectly permissible on SO (although I don't personally like to answer HW questions). Anything's possible, so your problem indeed might not be HW, but as phrased it sounds very much like a cut-and-pasted HW question. But precisely because it's so hard to tell if something is actually HW or not, the SO criterion becomes "is there evidence of research effort?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To find `D`, `E`, and `F` you may want to look at `summary.lm`. In particular,

```
ans$coefficients <- cbind(Estimate = est, `Std. Error` = se, 
    `t value` = tval, `Pr(>|t|)` = 2 * pt(abs(tval), rdf, 
        lower.tail = FALSE))
```

Hence, the values of interest are

```
2 * pt(abs(c(-3.725734, 1.213905, -3.038914)), 21, lower.tail = FALSE)
# [1] 0.001249329 0.238260061 0.006240436
```

respectively. That is, we use the t values from the table. The fact that `rdf`, the number of degrees of freedom, is 21 comes from

```
Residual standard error: 0.754 on 21 degrees of freedom
```

Comment: Thank you! How may I check the solution?

Comment: The quickest and probably convincing enough way would be to apply this formula to the t value of the intercept: `2 * pt(abs(1.325), 21, lower.tail = FALSE)` gives `0.1994086`.